# sql for product and category data

Tags: magento-1.8, database

I want to fetch below data from my magento 1.8 database in a single query.

sku, 
name,
model_no,
category name,
Brand,
price,
special price,
cost,
tax,
status

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a SQL query, the best way to create the query is by using Magento.  Create a product collection, adding the fields/attributes that you want to the collection, then output `$productCollection->getSelect()->__toString();`

This will output the SQL query that Magento would use to get the data that you want.

Comment: recently this project assign to me and i need this data for reporting purpose only and i am new to megento so i am not able to fetch the data from it because it db structure is bit complex